# Vertical margin on link in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, hyperlink, margin

I have a very very simple layout and design, but I cannot set the vertical margin of a link. Here is a shortened example:

```
<a href="http://www.google.de/">Google</a>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/" style="margin-top: 20px; ">YouTube</a>
<a href="http://www.foo.de/">Bar</a>
```

Everytime the second link have the same margin as all other links. Is this a bug of Google Chrome and how to resolve this problem?

**Edit**:
Is there a way to resolve it without wrapping the link in a `div`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<a href="http://www.google.de/">Google</a>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/" style="display:inline-block;margin-top: 20px;">YouTube</a>
<a href="http://www.foo.de/">Bar</a>
```

Comment: Thank you. With `display: inline-block;` it works :)

Comment: I've changed my answer to reflect that! Thanks @Cubinator73 and glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="http://www.google.de/">Google</a>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/" style="position:relative;top:20px;">YouTube</a>
<a href="http://www.foo.de/">Bar</a>
```